# Conditional onclick funtion firing without click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, react-props

I have set up a conditional element on click on a button I've made within react. but default prop runs onload without clicking the button how can I fix this issue?

the button looks like this:

```
<p onClick={Butter + Milk + Bread + Soup + Cheese > 0 ? props.next_ClickHandler : alert('Please Input some food!')}>Buy Now!</p>
```

I would like it so that if the values add to greater than 0 the props are passed but if not an alert is played why it this not working as intended?

Edit full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Data from '../shoppingData/Ingredients';
import { quantitiesContext } from '../shoppingData/Quantities';

const ShoppingPageOne = (props) => {

  //element displays
  const [pageone_show, setPageone_show] = useState("pageOne");

  //stores quantities of items as JSON objects
  const [Quantities, setQuantities] = useContext(quantitiesContext);

  const quantities = useContext(quantitiesContext);

  const Bread = quantities[0].Bread.quantities;
  const Milk = quantities[0].Milk.quantities;
  const Cheese = quantities[0].Cheese.quantities;
  const Soup = quantities[0].Soup.quantities;
  const Butter = quantities[0].Butter.quantities;

  useEffect(() => {
    //sets info text using Json
    if (props.showOne) {
      setPageone_show("pageOne");
    } else {
      setPageone_show("pageOne hide");
    }
  }, [props.showOne]);


  return (
    <div className={"Shopping_Content " + pageone_show}>


      <div className="Shopping_input_aligner">
        <div className='Shopping_input_container'>
          {Data.map((Ingredients) => {

            //updates Quanties Hook
            const handleChange = (event) => {

              setQuantities({
                ...Quantities,
                [Ingredients.Name]: {
                  ...(Quantities[Ingredients.Name] ?? {}),
                  quantities: event.target.value
                }
              });
            };

            return (<div className={"Shopping_input " + Ingredients.Name} key={Ingredients.Name}>
              <p>{Ingredients.Name} £{Ingredients.Price}</p>
              <input onChange={handleChange.bind(this)} min="0" placeholder="Input food quantity" type="number"></input>
            </div>)
          })}
        </div>

        <div className='Discount_list'>
          <h3>Discounts:</h3>
          <li>Buy one cheese get one free!</li>
          <li>Buy a Soup get a half price bread!</li>
          <li>A third off butter!</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Shopping_Buttons">
        <p onClick={() => {Butter + Milk + Bread + Soup + Cheese > 0 ? props.next_ClickHandler : alert('Please Input some food!')}} >Buy Now!</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default ShoppingPageOne;
```

Comment: can we see more of the code please? I think it would be better to check the condition in a function that is triggered every time one of your values changes (with componentDidUpdate or useEffect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a cleaner code with something like this if you're using React Hooks

```
const [ingredientsGreaterThanZero, setIngredientsGreaterThanZero] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (butter + milk + bread + soup + cheese > 0) {
    setIngredientsGreaterThanZero(true)
  } else {
    setIngredientsGreaterThanZero(false)
  }
}, [butter, milk, bread, soup, cheese]);

...

{ingredientsGreaterThanZero ? 
  <p onClick={props.next_ClickHandler}>Buy Now!</p> :
  <p onClick={() => alert('Please Input some food!')}>Buy Now!</p>
}
```

Comment: This is great and does fix my solution! my only issue is I still don't know why the other didn't work?

Comment: it's because you have to pass a callback to your onClick, for example : ```onClick={console.log('log')}``` becomes ```onClick={() => console.log('log')}```// see react docs : https://en.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 2):

```
<p onClick={() => { Butter + Milk + Bread + Soup + Cheese > 0 ? props.next_ClickHandler : alert('Please Input some food!')}}>Buy Now!</p>
```

Can you try using this?

Comment: tried that unfortunately it won't even compile

Comment: if next_ClickHandler is a function you should change that to next_ClickHandler(). It should compile

Answer (score 2):

**Reason**

If you attach any event in element with `onClick()` or any other event handler,
You shouldn't add any function invocation like in your example `alert()`.
Because, of parentheses `()` the function runs when component mounted in dom.

**Example:**

`<p onClick={alert('runs on load')}>wrong way</p>`

**Solution**
You have to add an empty function and and writes your codes in it. If your codes contain function invocation `( with parentheses () )`.

**Example:**
`<p onClick={() => alert ('only runs on click')}>right way</p>`

**Happy Coding :)**